# Student Code: map function not functioning

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, code-review

We made this code in class:

```
 int red = 6;
  int green = 7;
  int blue = 8;
  int pot = A0;
  int potVal = 0;
  int chosenColor = 0;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pot, INPUT);
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  potVal = analogRead(pot);
  chosenColor = map(potVal, 0, 1023, 1, 3);
  if(chosenColor = 1) {
    redCycle();
  }

  else {
    analogWrite(red,255);
  }

  if(chosenColor = 2) {
    greenCycle();
  }

  else {
    analogWrite(green,255);
  }


  if(chosenColor = 3) {
    blueCycle();
  }

  else {
    analogWrite(blue,255);
  }
  Serial.println(chosenColor);
  Serial.println(potVal);
  delay(500);
}

void redCycle() { 
    analogWrite(red,0);
  for(int i=0; i < 256; i+=5) {
    analogWrite(red, i);
  }
}

void greenCycle() {
  analogWrite(green,0);
  for(int i=0; i < 256; i+=5) {
    analogWrite(green, i);
  }
}

void blueCycle() {
  analogWrite(blue,0);
  for(int i=0; i < 256; i+=5) {
    analogWrite(blue, i);
  }
}
```

When we open the serial monitor we find that chosenColor is always 3 regardless of what the potVal is reading. I am sure is something simple but we can't find where is the error. Please help.

Comment: `analogWrite()` doesn't work on pins 7 and 8, only on those bearing the "~" symbol.

Comment: Ok that is one problem we didn't think about! Thank you. Still not sure why the map function is not working.

Comment: `chosenColor = 3` means “let `chosenColor` take the value `3`”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Edgar Bonet pointed out,  “`chosenColor = 3` means 'let chosenColor take the value 3'”.  That is, your  `potVal = analogRead(pot);  chosenColor = map(potVal, 0, 1023, 1, 3);` sequence may very well be working, but by the time you get to `Serial.println(chosenColor);` you have changed `chosenColor` to 3.

First, the statement `if(chosenColor = 1) {...}` changes `chosenColor` to 1. Then the statement `if(chosenColor = 2) {...}` changes `chosenColor` to 2.  Finally, `if(chosenColor = 3) {...}` changes `chosenColor` to 3, just before you print out the current value of `chosenColor`.

When you wish to compare two numeric values for equality, use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Aha! I get it. So I need to use ==. We will change that.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `=` (assign) with `==` (compare).

eg.

#### Wrong! ...

```
if (chosenColor = 3)  // this assigns 3 to chosenColor
```

#### Correct:

```
if (chosenColor == 3)   // compare
```

---

> Still not sure why the map function is not working.

You just *assumed* it is not working. Before making assumptions like this do a Serial print to show what the return value of the map function is. (Directly after calling `map` - not later on in the code).

Comment: I thought that <= would mean less or equal than. How would I do a greater than or equal to?

Comment: <= reads "less than or equal to"; >= is "greater than or equal to".

Answer (score 0):

Although not related to your main problem, I would like to point out
that there *is* an issue with your use of the `map()` function. Or maybe
I should say, with the `map()` function itself. Since it works with
integer arithmetic, and integer division by default rounds towards zero,
you get a mapping that may be quite different from what you expect.

In the table below, I am showing the result of
`map(potVal, 0, 1023, 1, 3)`. The column labeled “not rounded” is what
you would get if the mapping was done in floating point. The last column
is the rounded value you actually get out of `map()`:

```
potVal  not rounded  rounded
----------------------------
    0     1.00000       1
            ...
  511     1.99902       1
  512     2.00098       2
            ...
 1022     2.99804       2
 1023     3.00000       3
```

As you see, you have 512 possible values of `potVal` mapped
to 1, 511 values mapped to 2 and one single value mapped
to 3.

I assume you would rather have one third of the range mapped to each
value. This can be achieved by writing `map(potVal, 0, 1024, 1, 4)`:

```
potVal  not rounded  rounded
----------------------------
    0     1.00000       1
            ...
  341     1.99902       1
  342     2.00195       2
            ...
  682     2.99805       2
  683     3.00098       3
            ...
 1023     3.99707       3
```

This gives 342 values mapped to 1, 341 values mapped
to 2 and 341 values mapped to 3. Now, the problem is that
this way of using `map()` is confusing. You may prefer to write
something more explicit instead, like:

```
if (potval < 1023/3) chosenColor = 1;
else if (potval < 1023*2/3) chosenColor = 2;
else chosenColor = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I wanted a slider with a range of 0 to 200 to give 3 values; 0 for the first third of movement, 1 for the second third and 2 for the last third

I used map(slider value, 0, 134, 0, 2)